# Add an extra button in product view

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I'm trying to add a new extra "**add to cart**" called (Send as a gift)  button in product view. The functionality of this button has to be a little different than the original button. When i press this second button , it has to redirect directly to checkout .

I mentioned that the original button is not redirect. So , in conclusion , first button does not need to redirect you to checkout, but the second it is necessary.

Can anyone can give me some ideas , how to do this?  I am using magento 1.9
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one!

In your `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml` add a button along with add to cart button.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check out') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/url') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Send as a Gift') ?></span></span></button>
```

Then add this script on this page itself:

```
<script>
 function setcheckoutLocation(location,chkout)
 {
  jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:location,
                success:function(data){
                     window.location.href = chkout;
                }
             });
}
</script>
```

This should work, I have tested it on Magento 1.9.2.4 !!
Good Luck

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Comment: One more question , if you want and can help me, i'm trying to create a session variable if the this button was pressed. What i was trying to do was to make it looks like this :                                                                         
'code'<?php 
  session_start();
   if (isset($_GET["sendasagift"]))
       {
   $_SESSION['variable']= "yes";
        } else {$_SESSION['variable']="no";}
    ?>'code'

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to rewritte in local : `app>code>core>Mage>Checkout>controllers>CartController.php`, clone `addAction()` in `addcustomAction()` then redirect to cart at the end in this new one `addcustomAction()` like this:

   ```
   ...

   $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
   ```
2. Your new button should looks like this:

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/addcustom', array('product'=>$_product->getId(), 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())); ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Send as a gift') ?></button>
   ```

Now your new button add a product to cart with redirecting to checkout/cart